# What does "slips me her business card" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, verbs

I am reading *Just One Day* for Gayle Forman and I want to know what "slips" means in this verb phrase:

> slips me her business card

Comment: This usage means "to give" ("gave me her business card") but there's an additional connotation here which is not totally clear without the greater context. "Slipping" something to someone can sometimes mean giving something to someone surreptitiously, as in a bribe for example. In this case, the word may be being used for stylistic effect only.

Comment: @Era: May as well write that as an answer.

Comment: it is the **first** definition of the transitive verb in [Oxford Dictionary online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/slip) and [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=slip), and others.

Answer (score 4):

I sympathize with OP on this one. I knew what definition I was looking for, but it took me a while to track this one down in [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/slip)

> **slip**
>    Verb, sense 17:
>    to put, place, pass, insert, or withdraw quickly or stealthily:
>    *to slip a letter into a person's hand.*

And even that doesn't *precisely* match OP's context syntactically (but hopefully the sense is clear). Essentially, *to **slip** someone something* is to ***give*** it to them, but always with some implication of speed and/or secrecy. Possibly so secretly that even the recipient doesn't know, as in [slip someone a Mickey Finn](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22slip%20someone%20a%20Mickey%20Finn%22) (spike someone's drink).

Comment: I'm not surprised you found a good definition. Nothing slips by you. ;^)

Comment: @J.R.: I've noticed lately that *dictionary.com* is becoming increasingly comprehensive. In future I shall make a point of checking there first whenever I'm looking for a specific but relatively uncommon meaning for a relatively common word. I don't know if it's worth calling attention to other closely-related usages. For example, to ***slip away*** is often a euphemism for ***die** (usually, after protracted illness)*, but it can also mean the same as ***slip off, slope off*** (leave a social context quietly, without anyone noticing). Surreptitiously ***putting oneself*** elsewhere.

Comment: -1 because it's the first definition in more than one common dictionary. See [my comment](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/75300/what-does-slips-me-her-business-card-mean#comment145107_75300). The question should be closed. The meaning is neither esoteric nor hard to find.

Comment: @NES: That surprises me - I know my first port of call was [Merriam-Webster](http://beta.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slip), and I couldn't find it there - and looking again now, the only transitive sense I see is *to take cuttings from (a plant)*. I know I checked another source before finding it in dictionary.com, but I don't recall which one. Whatever - it's not a matter of personal pride to me, but in the interests of the site I think you should cancel that downvote. I don't think a correct answer to an "Off Topic" question can be justifiably downvoted.